# How to draw a graph in javascript while preserving the original relative positions?

Tags: javascript, graph

I would like to automate the generation of weathermap-like graphs. The idea is to store the GPS coordinates of the datacenters and the links between them.

The issue is that some datacenters are very close (a few kilometers) to each other while other are quite far (hundreds of kilometers). This would produce a graph with mainly blank space and a huge need to scroll :/

I am looking for a full js solution to "compress" the distances while preserving the relative positions.

any idea ?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Comment: this is completly different from what i am looking for. This lib is very nice to plot mathematical data wherehas i need to draw graphs...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compress but preserve the relative distance why not just decrease everything by a specific percent.  They maintain the same distance ratio just scaled down.

```
distance from orgin
100 miles
10 miles

scaled by a factor of 10

10 miles
1 mile
```

Same distance ratio just compressed...

or how about visually distance from the `+`

```
 10 spaces    5  
*          +     *

compressed

*     + *
```

Simple math to the rescue!

Comment: Actually, i want to preserve relative distances but not the proportions. It's kind of "liquid resizing".